# Why is WebAssembly blocked in Locker Service?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to use WebAssembly for a visualisation library within Aura components and LWC but it is blocked by locker service.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer

I assume it is possible to get this running on a vfp iframe but I would like to know if there is a specific reason for it being blocked and if I should raise a case about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Features that are blocked by Locker Service are universally so because they could potentially break free of Locker Service's constraints (e.g. accessing components it should not, or accessing data it should not). If Webassembly was allowed, presumably it would be able to access data it should not otherwise be able to. When, or if, Webassembly is allowed, it would be only after salesforce.com can guarantee that it would not be able to violate the security rules enforced by Locker Service. You can raise a case if you'd like, but you'd simply be told the same thing. Note that you can still choose to avoid the use of Visualforce by instead utilizing [lightning:container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm#!). This will allow you to create components that can be used in a Lightning context safely.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with container and let you know. Most major visualisation libraries are switching to WASM now so I assume Salesforce will have to support it eventually. They support d3 through LWC which is known to be shifting to WASM since 2017.

Comment: I have attempted to integrate the library though the lightning container but was unsuccessful. As the resource uses web workers, these violate CSP and so I get this error:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:xyz is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.